# Complete Measure spaces

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $\mu^*$ be an outer measure and $\mu$ be a measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$. $\mu^*$ can measure *any* subset of $\Omega$ while $\mu$ can only measure the sets in $\mathcal F$.

Let's take some set $A\subseteq\Omega$ that is not measurable. $\mu^*$ can assign a real value to that set but $\mu$ can't. One can complete a measure space though by "adding" all sets $A\subseteq B\in\mathcal F$ with $\mu(B) = 0$ to  $\mathcal F$.

It is clear that a measure constructed from an outer measure produces a complete $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F^*$ because for $B\in\mathcal F^*$ with $\mu^*(B) = 0$ it follows that $\mu^*(A) = 0$ for $A\subseteq B$ due to monotony. Moreover, $A\in\mathcal F^*$ since 
$$\begin{align*}
0&\leq\mu^*(A\cap Q) + \mu(A\cap Q^\complement)\\&\leq\mu^*(B\cap Q) + \mu^*(B\cap Q^\complement)\\ &= \mu^*(B)\\ &= 0,\end{align*}$$
so $\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(A\cap Q) + \mu^*(A\cap Q^\complement)$ for any $Q\subseteq\Omega$. Restricting $\mu^*$ to $\mathcal F^*$ gives then a measure.

My questions:

1. Completing the measure space was only concerned with null sets. What is with sets like $A\subseteq B\in\mathcal F$ and $\mu(B)>0$? Are they included in $\mathcal F^*$? Or does the term "completing" stems in fact from the fact that both approaches yield the same $\sigma$-algebras? (i.e. $\{F\cup N : \text{$F\in\mathcal F$ and $N$ is a null set}\} = \mathcal F^*$)
2. Given the complete measure space, can we resurrect the incomplete measure space? That is, given $\mathcal F^*$, can we construct $\mathcal F$?

Comment: Could you elaborate on question 1? What is the alternative approach that you are alluding to? Regarding question 2, I doubt anything can be done in general without additional information on how the measure was constructed.

Comment: From what I understood, there are 2 ways of completing a measure space: Either using an outer measure or "adding" the null sets to the $\sigma$-algebra. So I am refering to approach using an outer measure. Regarding your point to question 2: what if just an outer measure $\mu^*$ was given (which then gives raise to $\mathcal F^*$)?

Comment: If the original measure \mu is \sigma-finite, then the two approaches give the same measure space. The completion of \mu is the same as what you get from the outer measure approach. In general, the outer measure approach is the saturation of the completion of \mu.